# Cancan authorizing child state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

My setup: Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2, Cancan 1.6.5

My models:

```
class User
 has_many :projects

class Project
 has_many :tasks
 belongs_to :user

class Task
 belongs_to :project
```

ability.rb

```
can :manage, Task, :project => { :user_id => user.id }
```

What I need is to only allow access to a `task` if `user` and `project` are authorized and `project` has a certain status determined by a `project` instance method like `active?` (I have a reason for not making it just an attribute). What's the syntax for specifying the ability?

Answer (score 0):

Since access is given by calling a method (at runtime) you must [define the ability via blocks](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks). That will work for instances, and for index-like actions, you must engineer the query yourself.